# Crear lista simplemente enlazada en C con linux?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Hace algún tiempo utilicé listas enlazadas en C, pero haciendo uso del sistema operativo windows y el IDE Visual Studio, actualmente me encuentro haciendo uso de Linux (Ubuntu), y me doy cuenta que el compilador GCC, no me permite hacer las cosas como las hacía en windows.

Tengo el código de listas enlazadas que hice hace algunos meses, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar en linux, puede alguien darme alguna idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista {
    int valor;
    lista *prox;
};

lista *crear(int x) {
    lista *aux = new(lista);
    aux -> valor = x;
    aux -> prox = NULL;
    return(aux);
};

void insertarPorCabConRep(lista **p, int x) {
    lista *aux = new(lista);
    aux -> valor = x;
    aux -> prox = *p;
    *p = aux;
};

void insertarPorColaConRep(lista **p, int x) {
    lista *aux = *p;
    if(!aux)
        *p = crear(x);
    else {
        while((aux) && (aux -> prox))
            aux = aux -> prox;
        aux -> prox = crear(x);
    }
};

int buscarX(lista *p, int x) {
        while(p != NULL) {
            if(p -> valor == x)
                return(1);
            p = p -> prox;
        };
    return(0);
};

void eliminarXPrimeraVez(lista **p, int x) {
    lista *aux = *p, *aux2 = NULL;
    while(aux != NULL) {
        if((aux -> valor == x) && (aux -> prox != NULL)) {
            *p = (*p) -> prox;
            delete(aux);
            break;
        }
        else if((aux -> valor == x) && (aux -> prox == NULL)) { //Revisar esta parte porque da error cuando solo tiene un elemento
            aux2 = aux;
            delete(aux2);
            aux = NULL;

            break;
        }
        else if((aux -> prox -> valor == x) && (aux -> prox != NULL)) {
            aux2 = aux -> prox;
            aux -> prox = aux -> prox -> prox;
            delete(aux2);
            break;
        };
        aux = aux -> prox;
    };
};

void mostrarLista(lista *p) {
    if(p != NULL) 
        while(p != NULL) {
            printf(" [%d] -> ",p->valor);
            p = p->prox;
        }
    else
        printf("La lista se encuentra vacia.\n");
};

void main ( )
{
lista *A = NULL;
int n;
int op;
op=-1;
while (op!=0){
printf ("1.    Insertar elemento en lista por cabeza \"Con repeticiones\"\n");
printf ("2.    Insertar elemento en lista por cola \"Con repeticiones\"\n");
printf ("3.    Buscar elemento X en la lista\"\n");
printf ("4.    Eliminar elemento la primera vez que aparece\n");
printf ("99.   Mostrar la lista\n");

printf ("0.    Salir\n");
scanf_s("%d", &op);
switch (op){
case 1: 
    system("cls");
    printf(" \nIntroduzca el elemento a insertar en la cabeza de la lista: ");
    scanf_s("%i",&n);
    insertarPorCabConRep(&A, n);
break;
case 2: 
    system("cls");
    printf(" \nIntroduzca el elemento a insertar en la cola de la lista: ");
    scanf_s("%i",&n);
    insertarPorColaConRep(&A, n);
break;
case 3: 
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingrese el elemento que desea buscar: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);
    if(buscarX(A,n) == 1)
        printf("\n\nEl elemento %d si se encuentra.\n\n",n);
    else 
        printf("\n\nEl elemento %d no se encuentra.\n\n",n);
break;
case 4:
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingrese el elemento que desea eliminar de la lista: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);
    eliminarXPrimeraVez(&A,n);
    break;
case 99: 
    mostrarLista(A);
    printf("[NULL]\n\n");
break;

};
system("pause");
system("cls");
};
}
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/19610, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/19610, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879/19610 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/19610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era debido a que no es posible utilizar la función new en el compilador GCC, por tanto es necesario hacer uso de malloc para solicitar y reservar la memoria necesaria. A continuación comparto el código corregido.

```
typedef struct lista {
    int valor;
    struct lista *prox;
}nodo;

nodo *crear(int x) {
    nodo *aux = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    aux -> valor = x;
    aux -> prox = NULL;
    return(aux);
};

void insertarPorColaConRep(nodo **p, int x) {
    nodo *aux = *p;
    if(!aux)
        *p = crear(x);
    else {
        while((aux) && (aux -> prox))
            aux = aux -> prox;
        aux -> prox = crear(x);
    }
};

void mostrarLista(nodo *p) {
    if(p != NULL) 
        while(p != NULL) {
            printf("[ %d ]\n",p->valor);
            p = p->prox;
        }
    else
        printf("La lista se encuentra vacia.\n");
};

void contarElementos(nodo *p) {
    int i = 0;
    if(p != NULL) {
        while(p != NULL) {
            i++;
            p = p->prox;
        }
    }
    printf("Elementos de la lista: %d", i);
}
```

Comment: Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada.